# How to add a TextView to the top of a VStack in swift Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, layout, textview, textfield

I want to put a textview over the Textfield in my app. I am having some troubles adding a UITextView to over "Text("Hey") in my code.  When I try to, I get these error messages:

1. Type 'UITextView.Type' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
2. Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'UITextView' conform to 'View'

Do you have any tips on how to add a textview in the VStack over the textfield?

My code looks like this:

```
     VStack {
        Text("Hey")
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        TextField("Write here", text: $ingredients )
               Button(action: {
                let array = (self.ingredients.lowercased().components(separatedBy: " "))
```

}
}

Comment: Might be a problem with your brackets. Try selecting all your code, then pressing “Ctrl i” to reindent.

Comment: Wait also, ‘UITextView’? That’s from UIKit, will not work in SwiftUI. Use ‘TextView’ instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Text` for static Text and `Text Field` for editable Text in SwiftUI and avoid mixing it with UIKit.

If it's unavoidable, you can take a look at this [this guide](https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-textview-uiviewrepresentable/)